# Programmatically switch between views iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

As I am new to iOS programming, I am creating a light cycle game by a grid of views programmatically as:

```
- (void)createGrid
{
    float x=0,y=0;

    for (int i=0; i<288; i+=16) 
    {
        x = i + 16;

        for (int j=0; j<288; j+=16) 
        {
            y = j + 16;

            UIView *panel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 15, 15)];
            panel.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor ];
            [self.view addSubview:panel];    
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to switch between the views by changing the background colors for each view by clicking on up,down,left,right buttons.

Comment: means you want to swap the view by clicking?

Comment: hm..18x18 UIViews and all purple. Start using the -setTag method and give every UIView a tag in the grid so that when you use the buttons to go up/down/left/right, you can keep a track of the tag using some logic and ten you can go on from there to change the background color for that view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html), [UICollectionViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewCell) and [UICollectionViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/Reference/Reference.html) classes? Your panel looks like it could be a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
UIView *subview = self.view.subvies [i];
subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But if planning to have more complex game check out designed game engine instead of UIKit.